# For loop output to a string in python

Tags: python, string, for-loop, ascii

So i wrote a code that takes a string and print out the ascii code but i have this problem that i'm printing out the ascii for every letter in a for loop and in the end i want it to be a string of a number.

This is the code:

```
getname='test'
for letter in getname:
    print ord(letter)
```

And the output is:

```
116
101
115
116
```

How can i take the for loop output and make it a string?
in the end i want it to be like this:

```
116101115116
```

Thanks.

Comment: ''.join([str(ord(letter)) for letter in getname])

Comment: Maybe  need padding front a `0` for all fixed length.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a one line statement like this

```
>>> "".join(str(ord(x)) for x in getname)
'116101115116'
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a string and append to it, like this:

```
getname = 'test'
result = ''
for letter in getname:
    result += ord(letter)
print result
```

Output:

```
116101115116
```